# Solving the integral with norm vector over bounded region

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, euclidean-geometry, network, multigrid

I have to solve an integral like this:

$$
d =  \iint\limits_R{||x||^{-2/3} dA} 
$$

And the problem I have is described like this:

*there is a disk region R having an area of **100 m²**
and in this region we have about **150** clients placed in **hexagon** grid;
So, integrating above noted equitons has to provide us some idea about the relationship between average distance from the center point of the region to the hexagons in this region [see picture](https://ibb.co/g9cPhPc). I suppose it has also to contain some indicators about basic principles of contracted honeycomb geometry where the centers in hexagons are placed much more sparsely as one moves increasingly far from the central point of the region.

now, it looks very simple but I cannot figure out how I define integral bounds or what is the norm vector ||x|| in such case. Is this a distance in the region or the distance between hexagon centers?

in conclusion, my variable *d* has to result a value close to 46,91...(I just calculated it backwards because I know that for the circle region with 100m² and 150 Clients the optimal value is 28 hexagons. and for instance for 1500m² and 1000 clients we need 131 hexagons. and in this case, with 1000m² *d* approximates the value 220) but all my attempts to get this value through integration have failed.

If you want to go deeper look inside this paper:

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a3c0/4a840463275ca342b55de7bc7b8729a76750.pdf?_ga=2.230926559.1169654219.1590575403-354771040.1590445538

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ummmn...   why do you consider $c^\prime$ and invoke the inverse than instead talking about another variable $d = 1/c^\prime$?  You don't seem to be seeing through this issue.

Comment: thanks for your prompt  response, David! 
so, you say.. with the anothere variable d I could somehow approach the solution? what is the background behind this

Comment: To better understand my recommendation about paring down to basics, go to this page and search my solution:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: dear mr Stork, 
big thanks for your advice. I have just edited my issue. hopefully it will be more clear now

Comment: Make it *simpler*:  $$d = \iint\limits_R ||x||^{-2/3} dx$$.  When someone answers this simpler version, you *HAVE* your answer.  Can you see this?